# UITableView programmatically in Swift Empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a `UITableView` in swift programmatically. With the following code (I have `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in there):

```
var tableView = UITableView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(25, 180, 220, 150)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return options.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]

    println("cell label is")
    println(cell.textLabel!.text)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}
```

The table is coming blank, however. The cells don't show up. Any advice?

Comment: `println("cell label is")`, did it print anything?

Comment: nope it isnt. but the options array is being filled.

Comment: It means `options.count` has problem. Can you try print `options.count` int ?

Comment: Do you want options.count sections? and 1 row? `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return options.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
`

Comment: Why tableView.delegate initialized twice in viewDidLoad?One of them must be datasource isn't it?

Comment: `var tableView = UITableView()`. Can you try to create a var of tableView in .h file?

Comment: ah merge you found it. yes it should have been datasource. typo on my part. it's all working now. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why tableView.delegate initialized twice in viewDidLoad?One of them must be datasource isn't it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(25, 180, 220, 150)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.datasource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `tableView.reloadData()` after adding it to `self.view` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Print your options.count to see if you have data to show.

Comment: If you have only 1 row per section why use section? Move `return options.count` to `numberOfRowsInSection` and delete `numberOfSectionsInTableView` (the default is 1)

Comment: the options array is being filled. i print it after i query. right after that, i do tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Post the actual code please, there is no print in the one you posted. Are your delegates called?

Answer (score 0):

Not only you are missing **self.tableView.reloadData()** . What do you have inside of the data structure **options** where are you getting the data from?

you said you are Querying from parse :

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "whatever class name")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject]{

                for one in newObjects {


                    var message = one["TextMessage"] as! String
                    // so add this data message data into your array 
                    // then reload Data
                }

            }

        }
        else{
           print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

**And also** change this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 1
  }
```

To

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return options.count 
 }
```

Comment: I'm querying my database (using Parse), for them using a synchronous query. I have checked and the options are loading fine. After the query, I'm doing tableView.reloadData()

Comment: i do not think parse code is the issue, as the query is populating the options array. i am printing that array and seeing that it is populated. after i query parse and the array is filled, i do tableView.reloadData() so the issue has to be something else

Comment: ok read the last part of my edit you have mixed up the row method with the section method

Comment: good call on the changing numberofrowsinsection thing. that was a typo on my part. but the issue still persists :/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you (unconventionally) use each element in `options` as i row in its own section. But, when you set the label, you base it on the row number, which will alway be zero. What you want is:
`cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.section]`

As for the table being blank, I would think that either

1. Your first element is nothing
2. The array is empty
3. You are not setting up the sections properly